# Woocommerce - Query filter author product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, elementor

I have an archive page where I show the products related to the authors. But the widget I use only lets me select "Current Query" and only shows me the full list of author products without being able to edit any more features.

I am interested in editing the number of products to display and being able to filter by featured products.

I see it lets me link a custom Query filter from ID but I don't understand how to build a code for it to work. I'll give you an example of how the code is but this case for posts.

```
    // Showing multiple post types in Posts Widget
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    // Here we set the query to fetch posts with
    // post type of 'custom-post-type1' and 'custom-post-type2'
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'custom-post-type1', 'custom-post-type2' ] );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If that action actually exists then all you have to do to filter the author is to set a query parameter on the author part, the available options are:

(taken from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters here)

```
author (int) – use author id.
author_name (string) – use ‘user_nicename‘ – NOT name.
author__in (array) – use author id (available since version 3.7).
author__not_in (array) – use author id (available since version 3.7).
```

So you should do something like:

```
$query->set( 'author_name', 'my_author_nicename' );
```